# add newline for each chaining statement in visual studio code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0, prettier, prettier-eslint

anyone knows what is setting to add newline on chaining statement for prettier extension at visual studio code? I have code as following in typescript

```
export function myfunction(myString: string) {
  cy.get(myString).find('.aaa').click();
}
```

I want to make sure it turn into

```
export function myfunction(myString: string) {
  cy.get(myString)
    .find('.aaa')
    .click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `newline-per-chained-call` rule from eslint: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/newline-per-chained-call

Add this in your aslant config (`.eslintrc.json`, for example):

```
{
  //... 
  "rules": {
    //...
    "newline-per-chained-call": "error"
  }
}
```

To make it work in VS Code, install [eslint ext](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) and follow instructions how to "Auto Fix on Save" from ext page.

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll": true
}
```

for example.